# How to identify and fix device heat in iOS application developed using react native 0.72.0

Tags: ios, react-native

We have an application developed in react native 0.72.0 and we started observing device heat problem in iOS devices.

We have run the cpu report and run xcode time profile to check the cpu usage and observed random cpu spikes but couldn't able to find the root cause.

Cpu report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've handle important performance issues in huge React Native projects before, and it's not always trivial. In the end, what is gonna help you is `isolating` the problem, and it could be the case that something in your app is running in `loop`.

Here are some steps that might help you get closer to where the problem is.

1. Launch the app and don't use it for a while, and check CPU stats. If stats are normal, good; if not, it means something that is being run upon app launch might be causing the issue (services running in loop, unnecessary re-renders, etc).
2. If first step doesn't trigger CPU issues, go screen-by-screen or tab-by-tab on your app, `don't open them all at once`, so you can `isolate` the problem, until you open one specific screen that changes CPU/Memory usage (as per the screenshot, your app seem to be using a lot of memory too, which is not always a problem, but I'd recommend that you add screenshot for memory usage as well). Always wait a while before opening the next screen/tab, since CPU/Memory usage might take a while to spike. If you find a specific screen that is causing the CPU usage to spike, you can dig deeper from there.
3. Check for components re-renders, how hooks are setup, and mainly how you're working with `Redux` or other state container. It might be the case that actions are being dispatched in `loops`, where `action1` triggers `re-render1`, which triggers `action1` again etc.
4. Check your 3rd-party libraries. If you're using libraries that are unmaintained, or that are not very well-known by the ReactNative community, that could [potentially] mean a risk to your app, both in performance and security as well. Of course most libraries start out small and unknown, but the least downloads a library has, the least likely it is that someone will find a problem in it and repot it to NPM.

Comment: Dear @Henrique Mazer, we are observing this issue specifically on iOS devices 17 and above, the same application is working fine in android without any heat issue.